# NoSuchElementException - Selenium driver.find_element_by_link_text

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

I am having issues clicking on a link on a page. Basically I need to navigate to the device page on this site as seen in this picture:
[Want to click on "Devices"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiajm.png)

Currently, this the code that I am using:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Devices').click()
```

This is the inspection window: [inspection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrhBo.png)

```
<a href="device-inverter.html?plantId=1097806&amp;plantName=Wind%20Harvest" language="word164,设备" active="">Devices</a>
```

I want to click on this href. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The website has to be logged into so I cannot share all my code but here is what I have with the login credentials changed:

```
url_inverter = 'https://m.ginlong.com/main.html?class=device&subClass=inverter&page=view'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url_inverter)
driver.find_element_by_path('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[1]/input').sendkeys('myemail')
driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div[2]/input').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]').click()
```

At this point in my code I get to this page: [Page I get stuck on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFVpi.png)
Here is the inspection for this page:[Inspection for page I am stuck on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6aj7.png)

Here is the page I want to get to: [Page I want to navigate to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTXSn.png)
Here is the inspection for this page: [Inspection for next device page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMcYk.png)

Once I am on this page I want to click on the inverter and get to this page:  [Final page I want to navigate to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbUzG.png)
Here is the inspection for this page:[Want to click on export data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSvtg.png)

Ultimately I want to export data to python in order to manipulate it for data analysis. If you have any advice on that I would also be interested. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share ALL your code and a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet You have to log on to the page so I can't share everything but I have updated to post with a lot more information. Let me know if you want anything else! Thanks!